# Pagespeed work on localhost but not on virtualhost

Tags: apache, mod-pagespeed

I've compiled pagespeed 1.11.33.4-0 on Centos 7 over Apache on Cpanel server.

After compiling and create rpm, I've installed rpm module and create dir /var/mod_pagespeed/cache/ with permission for apache.

If test localhost work fine, almost if try verify with curl

```
curl -I localhost
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2017 06:14:45 GMT
Server: Apache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Mod-Pagespeed: 1.11.33.4-0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache
Content-Length: 111
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

If try any virtualhost not work.

```
curl -I tamainut.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2017 06:12:51 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://tamainut.com/
Cache-Control: max-age=0, public
Expires: Thu, 27 Apr 2017 06:12:51 GMT
Vary: User-Agent
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

On Apache2 httpd.conf

```
Include /etc/apache2/conf.modules.d/*
```

And on /etc/apache2/conf.modules.d/456_pagespeed.conf

```
<IfModule !mod_version.c>
  LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
</IfModule>
<IfVersion < 2.4>
  LoadModule pagespeed_module modules/mod_pagespeed.so
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.4.2>
  LoadModule pagespeed_module modules/mod_pagespeed_ap24.so
</IfVersion>
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
  ModPagespeed on
  ModPagespeedInheritVHostConfig on
  AddOutputFilterByType MOD_PAGESPEED_OUTPUT_FILTER text/html
  ModPagespeedFileCachePath            "/var/mod_pagespeed/cache/"
  <Location /mod_pagespeed_beacon>
        SetHandler mod_pagespeed_beacon
  </Location>
  <Location /mod_pagespeed_statistics>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from localhost
      SetHandler mod_pagespeed_statistics
  </Location>
</IfModule>
```

I don't understand who to I can to correct this problem, and on logs I don't see anything.

Comment: Try on a page that doesn't redirect. In your case, test the domain with a trailing slash. You can't really get a page speed header on a 301...

Comment: Realy work... Today I learn any more.